# How to sum up the value of the radio button from tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

So this is my code, is there any way to sum up the variable value from the radio button, I need to calculate the total but I don't know how to change the Int() into integers.I have tried so many times but it keeps showing error.[enter image description here][1]

```
from tkinter import*

class Q1(object):


    def __init__(w):
        w.root=Tk()
        w.root.title('short quiz')
        w.root.geometry('400x300')
        Label(w.root,text='').pack()
        Label(w.root,text='What is your favourite fruit？',font=('Arial',15)).pack()
        Label(w.root,text='').pack()
        v1=IntVar()
        Radiobutton(w.root, text='Strawberry',font=('Arial',12), variable=v1, value='2').pack()
        Radiobutton(w.root, text='Apple',font=('Arial',12), variable=v1, value='3').pack()
        Radiobutton(w.root, text='Watermelon',font=('Arial',12), variable=v1, value='5').pack()
        Radiobutton(w.root, text='Orange',font=('Arial',12), variable=v1, value='10').pack()
        Label(w.root,textvariable=v1).pack()
        Label(w.root,text='').pack()
        Button(w.root,text='next',font=('Arial',10),command=w.nextToQ2).pack()
        Button(w.root,text='return',font=('Arial',9)).pack()
        print(v1)
        w.root.mainloop()

    def nextToQ2(w):
        w.root.destroy()
        Q2()

class Q2(object):
    
    def GoBackToQ1(w):
        w.root.destroy()
        Q1()

    def end(w):
        w.root.destroy()
        TheEnd()

    def __init__(w):
        w.root=Tk()
        w.root.title('short quiz')
        w.root.geometry('400x350')
        Label(w.root,text='').pack()
        Label(w.root,text='What is your favourite colour？',font=('Arial',15)).pack()
        Label(w.root,text='').pack()
        v2=IntVar()
        Radiobutton(w.root, text='red',font=('Arial',12), variable=v2, value=2).pack()
        Radiobutton(w.root, text='yellow',font=('Arial',12), variable=v2, value=3).pack()
        Radiobutton(w.root, text='blue',font=('Arial',12), variable=v2, value=5).pack()
        Radiobutton(w.root, text='black',font=('Arial',12), variable=v2, value=10).pack()
        Radiobutton(w.root, text='orange',font=('Arial',12), variable=v2, value=15).pack()
        Radiobutton(w.root, text='purple',font=('Arial',12), variable=v2, value=20).pack()
        Label(w.root,textvariable=v2).pack()
        Label(w.root,text='').pack()
        Button(w.root,text='check your total points',font=('Arial',10),command=w.end).pack()
        Button(w.root,text='return',font=('Arial',9),command=w.GoBackToQ1).pack()
        w.root.mainloop()

class TheEnd(object):

    def __init__(w):
        w.root=Tk()
        w.root.title('short quiz')
        w.root.geometry('400x350')
        Label(w.root,text='').pack()
        Label(w.root,text='Your total marks are',font=('Arial',15)).pack()
        Label(w.root,text='').pack
        total=int(v1.get())+int(v2.get())
        Label(w.root,textvariable=total).pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Q1()
```

Comment: _"I don't know how to change the Int() into integers"_ - this is in the documentation. `v2.get()`.

Comment: `v1` and `v2` are local variables, so they cannot be accessed inside `TheEnd` class.

Comment: Oh i see! May i know how to modify the code so that I can sum up the values and print out the total in the end?I'm quite lost right now

Comment: Not two windows, maybe two frames in same window.

Comment: you should use `self.` to have access to widgets/variables in all functions/methods in the same class. If you want to access in other class then you should send it as arguments to other class. ie. `TheEnd(values)`. Besides if you use `destroy()` then you remove variables from memory and you can't access them. You have to get values before `destroy` and send to `TheEnd` as arguments.

Comment: using `Q1`  in `GoBackToQ1` doesn't go back to first `Q1` but it creates second `Q1` in memory.

Comment: better use `self.` instead of `w.` - it will be more readable for others. And see more in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.og/dev/pps/pep-008/)